# When is the right time to offer a draw according to the FIDE OTB rules

Tags: rules, draw, claim-draw

Is there any FIDE rule to say when is the right time to offer a draw?
To be more clear, shall I offer a draw when my clock is going or I should offer if my opponent's clock is running? In this situation if I offer a draw in my opponent move and he play a bad move, can he claim anything?

<sub>P.S: This happened to me, my opponent offered me a draw few seconds after he pressed the clock. Both position and time situation was in such a way that draw offer was already ridiculous, so to humiliate him, instantly after his offer I played a stupid move to say even if I do nonsense you will lose, but just after I moved I saw that this was one of the most stupid moves possible to play which cost me a rook and the game. Even that this was my mistake to get upset but my opponent in some sense played the man not the game and I think it was not fair.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

> 9.1.b.1 A player wishing to offer a draw shall do so after having made a move on the chessboard and before pressing his clock. An offer at
>   any other time during play is still valid but Article 11.5 must be
>   considered. No conditions can be attached to the offer. In both cases
>   the offer cannot be withdrawn and remains valid until the opponent
>   accepts it, rejects it orally, rejects it by touching a piece with the
>   intention of moving or capturing it, or the game is concluded in some
>   other way.
>
> 11.5 It is forbidden to distract or annoy the opponent in any manner whatsoever. This includes unreasonable claims, unreasonable offers of
>   a draw or the introduction of a source of noise into the playing area.

Comment: So in my case it seems condition 11.5 holds (and partially the other rule holds), then what is the consequence? can I claim to change the move? Or the opponent is losing because of violating rules? How arbiter should react? Also arbiter usually is not sitting on the board and in this cases the opponent can say whatever he want and no one can prove, he can even that he didn't offer a draw.

Comment: The consequences are laid out in Article 12.9, which has 8 escalating penalties starting with 1) a warning, 2) increasing your time, 3) decreasing your opponent's time. You would have to complain immediately and I am sure that the arbiter would simply issue a warning; this is a trivial rule violation. You cannot change your move, as you made it.

Comment: Thanks, this completes your answer, please move your comment to the answer then I'll accept it.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri I wonder if it's actually a warning; 11.5 still means that you have to distact the opponent, if it is immediately after pressing the clock he might've just done it the other way round, so there's no actual extra "distraction".

Answer (score 2):

The rule is, that you can only offer a draw in your own time (you shouldn't do nothing that can disturb your opponent when he thinks, and a draw offer is like that), you should offer a draw, then make a move, and handle your clock. Both players are supposed to signal that there was a draw offer, and it cannot be taken back.

Then the other player considers the offer, he can accept, he can refuse, or he can just make a move which means that he refused (but it's considered polite to also say something like let's play on a little).

Comment: FIDE says to move first then offer the draw then punch the clock.